# Extract IP address from a file

Tags: grep

I have a log file where between the lines we have strings like " ,true-client-ip=[1.1.1.1]". I want to write a grep/sed command to extract the IPs from the file. What is the best way to extract this output and write it to another file?

`cache-control=[no-cache, max-age=0],origin=[https://www.example.com],pragma=[no-cache],te=[chunked;q=1.0],true-client-ip=[108.81.148.189],user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299]`

Comment: perhaps sed would a better fit?

Comment: @codingyo Can you let me know whether my solution worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

You can write the output of the grep command to a new file as follows:

```
 grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' yourlogfile.txt >> ipfile.txt
```

---

A second option would be to use the Perl dialect, and to use a lookbehind to extract the IP after the `true-client-ip` field.

```
grep -Po '(?<=true-client-ip=\[)[^\]]+' yourlogfile.txt >> ipfile.txt
```

---

**ipfile.txt** now contains:

`108.81.148.189`